# Extract feature for automation method using ERDAS Imagine 2013 software?

Tags: erdas-imagine, feature-extraction

I have Quickbird Satellite data, hence I want to extraction from Building foot prints using automation method.

Could you give whether its possible or not using ERDAS Imagine 2013?

Answer (score 1):

Could be interesting to experiment with these extensions: Imagine Objective for automated feature extraction and **Easytrace** for semi-automated feature extraction functions.

[enter link description here](http://www.earsel.org/symposia/2012-symposium-Mykonos/Proceedings/17-03_EARSeL-Symposium-2012.pdf)

Comment: So what was your results ? Did you get it to accomplished ?